# SQL - Select total of visits for each unique page

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the total of each unique page. However I'm not sure how to approach this. For example
If they are 12x index.php's and 64x home.php's. I need something like

```
PAGE  |  TOTAL
index.php | 12
home.php  | 64
```

My table is as follows:

```
id | page 
0  | index.php
1  | index.php
3  | home.php
etc
```

This will be used to get the total of each page for page visits

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Thank you, just figured it out now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PAGE, COUNT(id) AS TOTAL 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY PAGE
```